# What's the stock of a gun?

Tags: word-meaning, terminology

[image]

I understand that the frame of a gun is the large piece in the middle, and the slide is the large piece in the top, but I am not sure what the stock of a gun is. Also, did I make any mistake?

> The larger component parts of any GLOCK pistol - **the frame, the stock
>   and the slide** - are interchangeable between different models. ([source](https://us.glock.com/en/learn/glock-pistols/technology))

Comment: Eeewwww! Ugly gun picture.

Comment: From your edit I gather you are not happy with my answer. See my update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your picture is one of an anatomy of a handgun (pistol). Handguns do not have stocks. A gunstock or simply stock is the wooden or metal handle on a rifle that comes into contact with your shoulder. Here is what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_(firearms)) says about gunstocks:

> A gunstock or often simply stock, the back portion of which also known as a shoulder stock, a buttstock or simply a butt, is a part of a long gun that provides structural support, to which the barrelled action and firing mechanism are attached. The stock also provides a means for the shooter to firmly brace the gun and easily aim with stability by being held against the user's shoulder when shooting the gun, and helps to counter muzzle rise by transmitting recoil straight into the shooter's body.

Edit:

I see the edit you've made to your question. That line, seemingly from Glock's website, refers to an extension made for Glock pistols, mimicking rifle stocks and making pistols function more like a rifle. What it talks about is not included in your picture. Here are some examples of stock extensions.

[image]
[image]
[image]

It should be noted that although "stock kit" is used, some of these mechanisms are also called "conversion kit". Some manufacturers meticulously ask that their products **not** be called stocks. Check out [this page](https://www.tacticalshit.com/the-best-not-stock-for-your-glock/):

> The Flux arm brace is neither designed nor intended to be a stock.